# Refactoring two similar classes in java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have two classes in Java which basically act the same but one represents a multiplier and the other represents a divider.
I want to create a parent class which both of them can extend but I don't know how to do that. What should I pass to the parent class?
this are both of the classes I have created:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Divide extends Operator {
    
    private String DIVIDE = " / ";
    
    public Divide(Expression leftExp, Expression rightExp){
        super(leftExp,rightExp);
    }
    
    /*
     * We assume that our divider is not zero. If it is, then we can handle it with exceptions*
     */
    
    @Override
    public float calculate(HashMap<String,Integer> map) {
        return this.leftExp.calculate(map) / this.rightExp.calculate(map);
    }
    
    private String isWithParentheses(Expression exp) {
        return exp.getClass().getSimpleName() == "Variable" || 
                exp.getClass().getSimpleName() == "Number" ? 
                        exp.toString() : "(" + exp.toString() + ")";
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String leftExpString = this.isWithParentheses(this.leftExp);
        String rightExpString = this.isWithParentheses(this.rightExp);
        
        return leftExpString + DIVIDE + rightExpString;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.toString());
        
    }
    
}
```

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Multiply extends Operator {
    
    private String MULTIPLY = " * ";
    
    public Multiply(Expression leftExp, Expression rightExp){
        super(leftExp,rightExp);
    }
    
    @Override
    public float calculate(HashMap<String,Integer> map) {
        return this.leftExp.calculate(map) * this.rightExp.calculate(map);
    }
    
    private String isWithParentheses(Expression exp) {
        return exp.getClass().getSimpleName() == "Variable" || 
                exp.getClass().getSimpleName() == "Number" ? 
                        exp.toString() : "(" + exp.toString() + ")";
    }
     
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String leftExpString = this.isWithParentheses(this.leftExp);
        String rightExpString = this.isWithParentheses(this.rightExp);
                
        return leftExpString + MULTIPLY + rightExpString;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.toString());
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing a Map to calculate() rather than just (Integer, Integer)?

Comment: BTW: `exp.getClass().getSimpleName() == "Variable"` should be something like `exp.getClass().equals(Variable.class)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the symbol and the math operation to the super constructor:

```
public Multiply(Expression leftExp, Expression rightExp){
    super(leftExp,rightExp, " * ", (a, b) -> a * b);
}
```

and

```
public Divide(Expression leftExp, Expression rightExp){
    super(leftExp,rightExp, " / ", (a, b) -> a / b);
}
```

Then you can store these parameters in appropriate fields, and use them in the methods, e.g.

```
return leftExpString + symbol + rightExpString;

return fn.apply(this.leftExp.calculate(map), this.rightExp.calculate(map));
```

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but can a constructor receive a function? for example you wrote : (a, b) -> a / b

Comment: Yes. That is, for example, a `BinaryOperator<Float>`, or a `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Float>`, or whatever.

Comment: So in this case it's BinaryOperator<Float,Float> ?

Comment: No, [BinaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) only has a single type parameter: it takes two Ts and returns a T. So, `BinaryOperator<Float>`.